# Django: conditional 500 response depending on Accept header?

Tags: django, json

Django returns an HTML error template by default when an unhandled exception happens in a view.  I would like to return a JSON response instead, if the request had an "Accept: 'application/json'" header (but otherwise return the usual HTML).  How might I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify your own 500 view function, in which you should be able to modify the response accordingly. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#handler500

Answer (score 2):

Change your handler500 handler in urls.py:

```
handler500 = 'application_name.views.error_500'
```

Define view function:

```
def error_500(request):
    # check request header
    return HttpResponse( json.dumps(retval), mimetype='application/json')
```